# HTML placeholder

Tags: html

I have use placeholder attribute to give information for user what's the input needed.

1. Is there any browser that's incompatible?
2. How to remove the placeholder when I focus in the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Many older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder).
2. While you could with JavaScript, **don't do that**. If someone tabs into it, they don't know what they're supposed to input.

Comment: thx for ur response..for the second quest...
The design tell me to do that.so is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any browser that's incompatible?

Lots, but as `placeholder` is designed to provide a hint (such as an example) and not as a replacement for a real `<label>`, that shouldn't be a problem if you are using it properly.

> How to remove the placeholder when I focus in the textbox?

Trust the browser to do it.

If a browser doesn't support `placeholder` it won't render the text in the first place.